# Python: How can I modify dictionary values in a for loop alternating the keys?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, for-loop, key

I am new to Python (and to programming).

I'd like to modify a dictionary in a for loop by alternating the key of the dictionary. I wrote the following code, which was unsccessful, however:

```
#coding: utf-8
dict1 = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}
dict2 = dict.fromkeys(dict1.values(),[])

for key in dict2:
    if key == 'value1':
        dict2[key].extend(['test1', 'test2'])
    elif key == 'value2':
        dict2[key].extend(['test3', 'test4'])
    elif key == 'value3':
        dict2[key].extend(['test5', 'test6'])

print (dict2['value1'])
print (dict2['value3'])
```

I expected the results to be:

```
 ['test5', 'test6']
 ['test1', 'test2']
```

but I actually got:

```
 ['test5', 'test6', 'test3', 'test4', 'test1', 'test2']
 ['test5', 'test6', 'test3', 'test4', 'test1', 'test2']
```

I guess the problem might come from my making the dictionary from another dictionary using "dict.fromkeys", but I couldn't see why it is problematic even if it is the case.

Thanks for your attention. Looking forward to your suggestions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All values of `dict2` are actually the same list instance, since passing `[]` to `dict.fromkeys()` only creates one list instance.  Try

```
dict2 = {v: [] for v in dict1.values()}
```

Comment: I got the results I expected and I understand what I missed. Thank you!

Comment: @miyazaki_tara: If you like this answer the best, you should accept it.

Comment: this is documented here.. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#:~:text=All%20of%20the%20values%20refer%20to%20just%20a%20single%20instance%2C%20so%20it%20generally%20doesn%E2%80%99t%20make%20sense%20for%20value%20to%20be%20a%20mutable%20object%20such%20as%20an%20empty%20list.%20To%20get%20distinct%20values%2C%20use%20a%20dict%20comprehension%20instead.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you used a mutable object as the value initializer. It is the very same object for each value.

```
Python2> dict1 = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}
Python2> dict2 = dict.fromkeys(dict1.values(),[])
Python2> dict2
{'value1': [], 'value2': [], 'value3': []}
Python2> dict2['value1']
[]
Python2> id(dict2['value1'])
43895336
Python2> id(dict2['value2'])
43895336
Python2> id(dict2['value3'])
43895336
```

So you are extending the same list.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over `yourdict.keys()` (this returns a list so it will not be affected by any change to the dict)

Comment: Only dictionary values are modified inside the loop, which is fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `dict.fromkeys()` initializes each item *with the same object*.

```
dict2 = dict((x, []) for x in dict1.values())
```

Comment: Thanks! I now understand what I missed.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed-out, the problem is that your call to `dict.fromkeys()` associates a reference to the same empty list with each key it creates in the new dictionary. An easy solution is to make `dict2` a `defaultdict` class from the `collections` module and make the default value a separate newly created empty `list`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dict1 = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}
dict2 = defaultdict(list)

for key in dict1.itervalues():
    if key == 'value1':
        dict2[key].extend(['test1', 'test2'])
    elif key == 'value2':
        dict2[key].extend(['test3', 'test4'])
    elif key == 'value3':
        dict2[key].extend(['test5', 'test6'])

print dict2['value1']
# ['test1', 'test2']
print dict2['value3']
# ['test5', 'test6']
```